# Why do I get negative pixel values when rescaling an image with PIL in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, resize-image

I'm trying to rescale a 32x32 pixel image to 28x28 using PIL's resize function. I begin by reading in a PGM image whose pixel values are all either 255 or 0 (I verified by looking at the file). However, when I rescale, some pixel values turn negative.

```
currIm = Image.open(os.path.join(currSrc,currFile))
currIm2 = currIm.resize((28,28), Image.BICUBIC

imData = numpy.asarray(currIm)
imData2 = numpy.asarray(currIm2)
```

All the values in imData are either 0.0 or 255.0, which is what I expect. However, the 'anti-aliased' pixels in imData2 tend to be negative with values varying from 0 to -50 and generally around -30.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it? For what it's worth, both currIm & currIm2 have mode = 'F' (Float??)

Note:This does not seem to be a problem with Image.BILINEAR interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PIL implementation may actually be correct.

Some interpolation functions, including bicubic, are prone to "overshoot". Basically if the change in values in a small area is dramatic enough, the interpolation function can yield values outside the original range.

Take a look at the Wikipedia article on [Bicubic Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation#Use_in_computer_graphics). There's an example image demonstrating some of the effects and references to [acutance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acutance), [ringing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts#Overshoot), and [clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28signal_processing%29).

Comment: So to counteract, should I:    1. Force all negative values to become positive? 2. Rescale the image by making the 255's smaller or 3. Just move on to BILINEAR interpolation?

Comment: There's no one-size-fits-all solution here. I recommend identifying what artifacts are bad in this case and devise a procedure to avoid them. It will require experimentation.